# Google cloud functions deploy to different environments with cloud build

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, google-cloud-build

[trigger configuration image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYZsl.jpg)I want to set up a ci/cd pipeline for my gcp project based on cloud functions service. Right now I am able to deploy to gcp project from cloud build with a trigger when pushing code on the staging branch. 
My cloudbuild.yml file looks like this:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['functions', 'deploy', 'profile', '--region', 'europe-west1', '--trigger-http', '--runtime', 'nodejs8', '--entry-point', 'profile']
  dir: functions
```

After that I created a second gcp project as production environment, to isolate stage and prod environment. I tried to follow the same process with master branch this time. I created the trigger to deploy cloud function when pushing to master just like staging case but it fails to trigger build. Any ideas ?

Comment: Could you share the trigger you are using in cloud build? and which repository are you using?

Comment: What is failed? The cloudbuild processing or the trigger ?

Comment: @JoséSoní I use a bitbucket repository which is connected with staging and production gcp projects.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere gcp throws error "Failed to trigger build:... ". This process failed only for the second project while the trigger for the first project worked as expected.

Comment: Do you have things in Cloud Build logs? Is it the same issue with a manual trigger?

Comment: No, build is not triggered at all. I should maybe change firebase admin to use the second project. Same issue with manual trigger.

Comment: how did you formed the trigger, and is the access to bit bucket granted in the project that is failing?